# sddm fails to ignore users

Tags: kde, sddm

I'm running Arch Linux KDE. I would like [SDDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM) to ignore certain users. However, even after adding the following config file, SDDM still displays all users. I tried both usernames and user ID's for the HideUsers parameters. Neither worked (all users were still displayed).

*/etc/sddm.conf.d/uid.conf*

```
[Users]
DefaultPath=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
HideShells=/sbin/nologin,/bin/false,/usr/bin/nologin,/usr/bin/git-shell
HideUsers=sue,sam,joe,jess
MaximumUid=1005
MinimumUid=1000
RememberLastSession=false
RememberLastUser=true
```

I also tried doing the config via KDE system settings GUI with no results. In all cases, all users are displayed regardless of any config changes I make. There are no other config files in `/etc/sddm.conf.d/` and the main config (`/etc/sddm.conf`) does not have any conflicting settings. (In fact, I mirrored these settings in the main config and I tried this without any `uid.conf` at all, just using the main config. Again, all users are displayed regardless of any config changes.)

#### EDIT

As the config file shows, I have specified HideShells. As a temporary test, I also tried setting certain user accounts to have the `/sbin/nologin` in `/etc/passwd`, but even that did not prevent these user accounts from being displayed by SDDM. Crazy.

Comment: Safe to assume this isn't the issue, right? - https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/626.

Comment: @slm - correct. That's a different issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that SDDM has, by default apparently, another config file located at `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/sddm.conf`. After editing that file the same way I had previously edited `/etc/sddm.conf.d/uid.conf`, the issue is solved.

As an aside, unless someone knows otherwise, I consider this a bug. Config files in `/usr/lib/` should not take precedence over config files in `/etc/`, right?